# How do I store class data in an array and recall this data as needed?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a version of the game Snakeeyes, which will take in n at the start of the program, n being the number of players.
So far, I have managed to get this far:

```
import random


def rollDice():
    dice = random.randint(1, 6)
    print "You rolled a", dice
    return dice


def addUser(name):
    name = player()
    print name, "is a player"


class player():
    score = 0
    players = []
    def __init__(self):
        score = 0
        player.score = score


    def addScore(self, dice1, dice2):
        if dice1 == 1 or dice2 == 1:
            player.score = 0
            if dice1 == 1 and dice2 == 1:
                print "SNAKE EYES"
        else:
            player.score += dice1
            player.score += dice2
        return player.score


    def dispScore(self):
        return player.score



numbp = int(input("Please enter number of players \n"))
plyarr = dict()
for x in range(numbp):
    plyarr[x] = player()
    plyarr[x].addScore(rollDice(),rollDice())

for x in range(numbp):
    print plyarr[x].score
```

However,I can't get it to work because of my naivety with how python works and how classes (etc) can be used to speed this sort of programming up. The main issue is that often it overwrites the same spot in the dictionary (if I use a dictionary).

Comment: Ok, first off, you are using a variable called player, in your class. It is not defined in the class. And where do you use players list?

Comment: Right, that variable is a remains of a previous attempt of getting the class to work with a loop. I use a players list after the dispScore() method but I haven't got anything working after that. I used to have a for loop after it, which would iterate through x until n and call the class to the players[x]

Comment: I re-wrote your player class in my answer. Could you check whether this class works as you intend? (I am not familiar with the game)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re written player class:

```
class player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.score = 0
        self.players = []


    def addScore(self, dice1, dice2):
        if dice1 == 1 or dice2 == 1:
            player.score = 0
            if dice1 == 1 and dice2 == 1:
                print "SNAKE EYES"
        else:
            self.score += dice1
            self.score += dice2

        return self.score


    def dispScore(self):
        return self.score

    def __str__(self):
        return '<a description of the current object>'
```

From your comment, I assume you are inquring about the way to store the players in a dictionary; you could do it as follows (did a small change to your original code)

```
numbp = int(input("Please enter number of players \n"))
plyarr = dict()

for x in range(numbp):
    current_player = player()
    current_player.addScore(rollDice(),rollDice())
    playarr[x] = current_player
```

And finally, display your players' scores:

```
for player_id, player in plyarr.items():
    print player.dispScore()
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks, but this doesn't solve my problem (sorry, it's poor communication on my end). How can I use a array (list/dict) as the variable that holds the class info?

Comment: Do you want to store the information that you have in the class currently, in an dictionary or a list? The class won't be used in that case? or do you want to store the objects in the class in a list or dict?

Comment: I want to declare a list or a dictionary with a size n (user chooses), use a for loop to cycle through it, and use the list/dict to organise the classes (so the program can retrieve the data using loops). Is this possible?

Comment: Could you confirm whether my updated answer solves the problem?

Comment: I am glad. One minor thing, if you want to call something like print on a class object, you need to override the __str__ method in the class, so it would print what ever you would like for a class object. Added that code to the answer too.